# RecurrenceRULE for Outlook2010 is not working

Tags: sharepoint, icalendar, rfc5545

I have a C# code which sends a .ics format calendar invite from sharepoint to Outlook or any other email clinet.

but for the outlook that invite is not valid .

Not supported calendar message when recurring event is there.

Can anybody help me with this ?

I am stuck

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the `iCalendar` file you sent nor the `RRULE` it is difficult to provide detailed answers.

What you should be aware though, is that few calendar are 100% compatible with the [latest iCalendar specs (RFC5545)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)

For instance you will find some of the documented **deviations** for outlook 2003 [here](http://www.calconnect.org/tests/iCalendar-RRULE-Interop/iCalendar-RRULE-Interop-Matrix.html).

Bottom line, to answer your question, you will need to proceed with trial and error on the different `iCalendar` syntax you want to have with all your clients until you find a least common denominator which works on all target clients.